# Is there a way to fit a normal curve to points?

Tags: matplotlib, statistics, curve-fitting

As a small project I've made a program the throws nd dice an nt number of times. At each throw it sums the results from the dice and adds it to a list. At the end the data is rappresented with matplot.

```
import random
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nd = int(input("Insert number of dice: ")) 
nt = int(input("Insert number of throws: "))
print(nd, " dice thrown ", nt, " times")
print("Generating sums, please hold....")
c = 0
i = 0
sum = 0
sums = []
while nt >= i :
    while nd >= c:
        g = random.randint(1, 6)
        sum = sum + g
        c += 1
    sums.append(sum)
    i = i+1
    c=0
    sum = 0
    print("Throw ", i, " of ", nt)
sums.sort()
max = max(sums)
min = min(sums)
print("||Maximum result: ", max, " ||Minimum result: ", min)

print("Now ordering results")

f = Counter(sums)
y = list(f.values())
x = list(f.keys())
print("Rappresenting results")

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("Risultati")
plt.ylabel("Frequenza")
plt.title("Distribuzione delle somme")
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The resultant graph looks something like this:
[image]

I would like to know how to fit a gaussian curve to the points in order to make the graph clearer

Comment: Well, if you compute the mean and standard deviation of the results, then by definition that defines the best-fitting Gaussian curve. You will need to scale the vertical axis to make the two curves align -- essentially you need to ensure the area under the empirical curve is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The mean and the standard deviation of the sums are the parameters needed for the Gaussian normal. The pdf of a distribution has an area of `1`. To scale it to the same size as the histogram, it needs to be multiplied with the number of input values (`len(sums)`).

Converting the code to work with numpy arrays, makes everything much faster:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

nd = 10000  # int(input("Insert number of dice: "))
nt = 10000  # int(input("Insert number of throws: "))
print(nd, "dice thrown", nt, "times")
print("Generating sums, please hold....")
sums = np.zeros(nt, dtype=np.int)
for i in range(nt):
    sums[i] = np.sum(np.random.randint(1, 7, nd))
sums.sort()
xmax = sums.max()
xmin = sums.min()
print("||Maximum result: ", xmax, " ||Minimum result: ", xmin)

print("Now ordering results")

f = Counter(sums)
y = list(f.values())
x = list(f.keys())
print("Plotting results")

plt.plot(x, y)
mean = sums.mean()
std = sums.std()
xs = np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1)
plt.plot(xs, norm.pdf(xs, mean, std) * len(sums), color='red', alpha=0.7, lw=3)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Here is some code to add to the code of the question, using numpy only for calculating the mean and the standard deviation.  (Note that as you use `sum` as a variable name, you get an error when you try to use Python's `sum()` function. Therefore, it is highly recommended to avoid naming variables such as `sum` and `max`.)

```py
def f(x):
    return norm.pdf(x, mean, std) * len(sums)

mean = np.mean(sums)
std = np.std(sums)
xs = range(xmin, xmax+1)
ys = [f(x) for x in xs]
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='red', lw=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is unclear to me what the xs variable is for.

Comment: The `xs` is an array of x-values needed to create the curve with `xs` on the x-axis and `f(xs)` on the y-axis (where `f()` is the desired gaussian normal).  It is the standard way of plotting a function with matplotlib and numpy.  Without numpy, you'd use something like `xs = range(xmin, xmax+1)` and `ys = [f(x) for x in xs]`.